# Python 2.7 how to match and extract a aprticular string

Tags: string, python-2.7

How can i read a file containing the following, match the staements with the SNMP RO passwords and select just the two passwords using python

```
!
route-map rm-receive-from-hot-vpn deny 10
 description do not accept default route
 match ip address prefix-list pl-default-route
!
route-map rm-receive-from-hot-vpn permit 20
 description receive all other routes
!
snmp-server community sader RO 1
snmp-server community 34567sdf RW 1
snmp-server community aswert RO 10
snmp-server trap-source Loopback0
snmp-server packetsize 4096
snmp-server tftp-server-list 1
snmp-server location  Ocean Grove
snmp-server contact Telstra IMS 1800 815 851
snmp-server enable traps snmp linkdown linkup coldstart warmstart
snmp-server enable traps vrrp
snmp-server enable traps pfr
snmp-server enable traps flowmon
snmp-server enable traps ds1
snmp-server enable traps ds3
snmp-server enable traps call-home message-send-fail server-fail
snmp-server enable traps tty
```

The two lines of interest are the following two lines. I would like to store the two SNMP RO passwords in a list SNMP_RO ['sader', 'aswert'].

```
snmp-server community sader RO 1
snmp-server community aswert RO 1
```

Comment: And what have you tried/considered?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f: # Open the file
    lines = f.readlines() # create list of lines 
    passwords = [] # Initialize list of passwords
    for line in lines: # Loop through lines
        parts = line.split() # Separate each part of current line into a list
        try:
            if parts[-2] == "RO": # Password if the 2nd to last item is "RO"
                passwords.append(parts[2]) # Add password to the list
        except IndexError: # Ignore index errors
            pass

print passwords
```